# Moxi v2.5 outdated library dependencies?

Tags: couchbase

I tried to see what libraries moxi (v2.5) depends on, and see if I can install the `moxi-server.deb` package in Ubuntu Trusty(14.04) with the same dependencies.

Here is what I got in Ubuntu v.12.04:

```
/opt/moxi/bin$ ldd moxi.actual
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff451fe000)
        libconflate.so.0 => not found
        libvbucket.so.1 => not found
        libmemcached.so.6 => not found
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd9112b9000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd910fbd000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd910d9f000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd9109df000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd9114c8000)
```

It seems it depends on `libconflate` and two other libraries. Is that simply outdated?

The Couchbase [Moxi repo](https://github.com/membase/moxi) seems to already include `conflate` and `libmemcached` source. So moxi should just work without those libs. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those libs are actually in `/opt/moxi/lib/`.